# How to find all data for date in a database, if criteria is met

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am not sure how to go about doing this. I have never tried an IF statement in SQL.
I would like to Pull all data for the date, ONLY if the where clause is true.

```
SELECT Distinct Name,Date,ID, Modifier
FROM Database
WHERE Date Between'09/01/16' and '03/31/17'

and ID in ('1','2','3','4')
and Modifier In ('A','B','C')

OR ID in ('1','2','3','4')
And Modifier IS NULL
```

**Example**

```
Name    Date         ID     Modifier        

Ted     01/01/01     1       A           = True
Ted     01/01/01     7       F           = True
Ted     02/02/02     7       F           = False
Ted     03/03/03     7       F           = True
Ted     03/03/03     1      NULL         = True
```

Any Help Would is appreciated.

Would this be easier with a excel fomula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you intend conditions like this:

```
WHERE Date Between '2016-09-01' and '2017-03-31' and
      ID in (1, 2, 3, 4) and
      (Modifier In ('A', 'B', 'C') or Modifier IS NULL)
```

Notes:
 - Use standard date formats, such as YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD.
 - Don't use single quotes for numeric values (I assume `id` is a number).
 - I am guessing that your logic wants the first two conditions and then modifier if it is A, B, C, or NULL.

Comment: Got it, Yep and if the condition is met I would like to see all the data I have on "ted" for that date.